# mysql order by MIN() where NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause, min

i have little bit long select, where I join many tables. What i need to do: I'm selecting lowest price with

```
SELECT MIN(accomodation_price.price) AS price_from
```

Everything works great till i want to order results by price_from. Ok i know i can't use ORDER BY price_from so i tried to use ORDER BY MIN(accomodation_price.price) but i want to use it in CASE. My select works good but it applies first results, which doesn't have any value for MIN(accomodation_price.price)... First i want results with some value, then others...

Here is my code, row with MIN.... is not working and i don't know why. I tried also to use WHERE IS NOT NULL but the same....

```
ORDER BY

            CASE 

                WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() THEN 0
                WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' THEN 1 
                WHEN MIN(accomodation_price.price) > '0' THEN 2
                ELSE 3 END";
```

Comment: What is the field type of accomodation_price.price?

Comment: i forget to add that, when there is blank result - it means there isn't any row in accomodation_price... So i don't know what mysql return in this case when i select MIN(accomodation_price.price)

Answer (score 1):

what you should do is include that field (along with `CASE`) in result dataset, wrap it with yet another `select` and then order by that field. Something like:

```
select * from
(select field1,field2,...,
(CASE 
WHEN accomodation.valid_to>=NOW() AND accomodation.valid_from<=NOW() THEN 0
WHEN NOW()>accomodation.valid_to AND accomodation.valid_to!='0000-00-00' THEN 1 
WHEN MIN(accomodation_price.price) > '0' THEN 2
ELSE 3 END) as field3 from table1,table2...,tableN) as R
order by R.field3
```